# How can enable user to paste an image from clipboard using vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, paste

In my template I have:

```
        <textarea @paste.prevent="fileChange" ref="canvas" /></textarea>
```

In my script, I have a method:

```
fileChange(event){

  console.log(event.clipboardData.items[0].kind) 

  ....

}
```

On my console, I keep getting a string when the fileChange event is trigged (by pasting).

Comment: You can't show an image in a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Technical_summary) element, only plain text is allowed.

Comment: Are there any DOM elements that can allow me to paste an image? I've tried this with a  <input type='file'> and <div> with no success.

Comment: Most of the elements accept an image as a content, including `div`. In general, form control elements don't  accept an image, (except `input type='image'`, but that's probably what you don't want to use). But you can't paste to a static element, try with a `div` which has `contenteditable` attribute set.

Comment: Still getting items of a string type on console sadly.

Comment: The image the browser selected from the clipboard is most likely in base64 format, which actually is a string.

Comment: I don't think it is. When i try console.log(event.clipboardData.items[0].type.indexOf('image')), I get -1,

Comment: If I copy an image from a web page, and paste it to a contenteditable div, browser creates an img tag similar to the original image has on its web page. If I copy the image from my local system, the browser creates an image tag with src of base64. Either way, the type of the cliboard item the browser selected, is text, either a copy of the image tag, or a base64 address. With "browser's select" I mean, that the content is stored in multiple forms on the clipboard, and the app you paste the content selects the most appropriate form from the alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

in my component i used this (listeningn  paste event)

```
                    <b-form-textarea
                            @paste="pasteFunction"                                
                    ></b-form-textarea>
```

and in my function got this

```
pasteFunction(pasteEvent, callback){

if(pasteEvent.clipboardData == false){
    if(typeof(callback) == "function"){
        console.log('Undefined ')
        callback(undefined);
    }
};

var items = pasteEvent.clipboardData.items;

if(items == undefined){
    if(typeof(callback) == "function"){
        callback(undefined);
        console.log('Undefined 2')
    }
};
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    
    if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) continue;
    var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
    this.addImage(blob)
}
}
```

Finally, i procces the image with another method

```
       addImage(file){
            if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
                return new Promise((reject) => {
                    const error = {
                        message: 'Solo puede arrastrar imágenes.',
                        response: {
                            status: 200
                        }
                    }
                    this.$obtenerError(error)
                    reject()
                    return;
                })
            }

            this.files.push(file);
            const img = new Image(),
                reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e) => this.images.push(e.target.result);
            const str = JSON.stringify(file);

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
           }
```

In my front can see all images like this

```
                    <div class="img-wrapper" v-for="(image, index) in dimg" :key="index">
                        <img style="max-width:230px; max-height: 230px;" thumbnail center rounded  class="max-image-upload" :src="image" :alt="`Image Uplaoder ${index}`">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please, include some kind of textual explanation about why you think your solution would work and/or about the reason for the question issue. Thanks!

Comment: This is simple and elegant code. I have taken some of it for a single file page from clipboard